# Android how to animate alpha and then translation?

Tags: android, user-interface, kotlin, animation, transition

I want to make **2 animations**, I have one view that will disappear once its touched(the one with emojis and "How do you feel today?"), with an alpha animation(from 1 to 0 alpha, at the end its visibility will be View.GONE), and then all the other views in the layout should slide up instead of them going up instantly. I have already done the alpha animation, the transition one is the one I can't achieve.

I am using Constraint Layout so what happens is as soon as the first view disappears changing its visibility to GONE, **the others move instantly up**. I have tried many ways, but I can´t find how to achieve this. I don't know what type of transition or animation should I use.

[image]

This is the code I am using fot the alpha animation:

```
    fun hideEmojiView(view: View) {
    val fadeOut: Animation = AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f)
    fadeOut.interpolator = AccelerateInterpolator()
    fadeOut.duration = 500

    fadeOut.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation) {
            view.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation) {}
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation) {}
    })
    view.startAnimation(fadeOut)
}
```

**UPDATE:** SOLUTION

I ended up making the suggestion @Tenfour04 made. The problem was that I was adding `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to a ScrollView and it needs to be added to a **ConstraintLayout, and it needs to be the direct parent of the view you are dissapearing**. So here is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        tools:context=".fragments.maincontent.TodayFragment">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/subtitle_font"
            android:text="Upcoming"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rv_daily_picks" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView6">

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView5">

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_welcome"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/title_font"
            android:text="Welcome, Sebastián"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/subtitle_font"
            android:text="Stories"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emoji_view" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_stories"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView7">

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/subtitle_font"
            android:text="Daily picks"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rv_stories" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_daily_picks"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_upcoming"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rv_upcoming" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/emoji_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_white_30alpha_background"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_welcome">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/subtitle_font"
                android:text="How do you feel today?"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/emoji1"
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_white"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textSize="26sp" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/emoji2"
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_white"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textSize="26sp" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/emoji3"
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_white"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textSize="26sp" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/emoji4"
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_white"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textSize="26sp" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/emoji5"
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_white"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textSize="26sp" />
                </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and my code:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val binding = FragmentTodayBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        val user = AppController.get<UserModel>(UserModel.key)
        binding.tvWelcome.text = "Welcome, " + user!!.name

        binding.emoji1.setOnClickListener{ binding.emojiView.visibility = View.GONE }
        binding.emoji2.setOnClickListener{ binding.emojiView.visibility = View.GONE }
        binding.emoji3.setOnClickListener{ binding.emojiView.visibility = View.GONE }
        binding.emoji4.setOnClickListener{ binding.emojiView.visibility = View.GONE }
        binding.emoji5.setOnClickListener{ binding.emojiView.visibility = View.GONE }

        return binding.root
    }
```

Comment: Add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to your ConstraintLayout.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I edited my post with your sugestion, but it didn't seem to work. I don't know if im missing something. I'm working on a fragment and using viewbinding. Thanks!

Comment: It needs to be set on the ConstraintLayout. The immediate parent of the view that’s removed.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I just made the change of android:animateLayoutChanges="true" from the scrollView to the ConstraintLayout parent of the view I remove and it worked! Thanks a lot man!